# google website translator prevent async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, localization, translation, google-translate

I'm trying to implement Google Website Translator (https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) but the behavior is pretty bad because it loads the original page first and then loads the translated version. The user sees the site in English for 2 seconds and then a 0.5 second refresh and then the translated version. It's not very user friendly.

I'd like it to only take .5 seconds for the translation. Is there a good way to do this? I'm thinking by making the script load synchronous it should help.

[image: It doesn't do anything until 3 seconds into the page load]

Image shows that it doesn't do anything until 3 seconds into the page load.